# Deleting item from Experience Editor throws exception for null ContentDatabase

Tags: experience-editor

Sitecore version: 8.1 update 3.

Whenever I try to delete an item in the Experience Editor, I get a browser prompt in the page ("Leave site? Changes you made may not be saved.") and if I confirm it, I am sent to the 500 error page and the below error is logged.

```
6648 09:39:24 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: The Sitecore.Client.ContentDatabase is null.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Client.get_ContentDatabase()
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ShellForm.RefreshLinks(Control parent)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ShellForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

Anyone seen this or have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Have you switched from on Sitecore Desktop to some other database in another tab (core/web)? Was there any code/config change that caused the issue?

Comment: Haven't switched databases somewhere else in the session (I can open it in EE and immediately delete it without changing anything and the problem happens). No recent config change that seems relevant.

Comment: Which Sitecore version exactly is this happening? Can you disable all custom configs and try again? Are you logged in as admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a strange one. It was our own custom code that caused it, but it's possible someone could run into a similar issue so I'll add my findings here.

## Relevant context

- We have an `item:deleted` event handler for pages that also deletes a corresponding item in a data folder.
- We have applied [Sitecore's 321270.321271.103751 hotfix](https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.321270.321271.103751) which updates the `\sitecore\shell\Applications\WebEdit\WebEditRibbon.aspx` file (used for the ribbon in the Experience Editor) and also the referenced `Sitecore.Support.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.WebEditRibbonForm`.

  - This change involves checking the site of current item to ensure links are generated properly
- The `WebEditRibbonForm` class has a `DeletedNotification(object sender, ItemDeletedEventArgs args)` method that is called for each item that's deleted which, in our case, was first the page and then the page's data folder.
- This `DeletedNotification(...)` method saves the ID of the parent of the item that was deleted so that, when the time comes, it could be redirected to

## What was happening?

So here's how it was happening that wasn't working:

1. User clicks delete in Experience Editor
2. `WebEditRibbonForm` receives `DeletedNotification` for page, saves parent ID of the page into `parentID` private field
3. `WebEditRibbonForm` receives `DeletedNotification` for page's data folder, saves parent ID of the page's data folder into the `parentID` private field
4. Deletions complete successfully
5. `WebEditRibbonForm` receives call to `Redirect()` method, which needs to respond with the URL to the page to load next (the parent of the deleted item is expected)
6. `WebEditRibbonForm` uses the `parentID` private field to look for the item and checks to see if it or any of its parents have layout details
7. They don't (because the `parentID` is in the data area, not a page), so it returns an invalid link
8. The page tries to redirect, but at the destination receives the error from the question

To fix it, I applied the following changes:

### Updated `WebEditRibbonForm`

Create a custom `WebEditRibbonForm` with a simple change:

```
public class CustomWebEditRibbonForm : Sitecore.Support.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.WebEditRibbonForm
{
    protected override void DeletedNotification(object sender, ItemDeletedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Only save the parent ID for redirection if this is a deletion notification for a page
        if (args.Item.IsDerived(new ID("ID-OF-BASE-PAGE-TEMPLATE")))
            base.DeletedNotification(sender, args); 
    }
}
```

### Updated `WebEditRibbon.aspx`

Update the CodeBeside to use the custom `WebEditRibbonForm`

```
<sc:CodeBeside runat="server" Type="Custom.CustomWebEditRibbonForm,Custom" />
```